# LibraryThing: How do I tell the bug collectors that the site is completely broken?

Tags: javascript, https

First, most of the web page is completely broken when using HTTPS, because they're using the css.librarything.com and js.librarything.com domains to serve CSS and JavaScript (without which the site unfortunately doesn't work at all), and the certificate doesn't cover those domains.

Second, I can't [submit a message](http://www.librarything.com/talktopic.php) to the Bug Collectors group via the HTTP site, because the JavaScript there is also broken:

```
Error: $("fp0") is null
Source File: http://js.librarything.com/minified/js/[...].js
Line: 823
```

Does someone know some way to alert the site admins now?

Comment: I don't get it. I've seen many useful questions getting closed. But this sort of questions are being top new questions. This question should be closed because it's too localized.

Comment: Why is this too localized? This site *is* for questions about individual web apps, and I couldn't find anything in the FAQ arguing against it. Also, it could help anyone else if/when this happens again (HTTPS was broken for a long time once before).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Questions about LibraryThing in general, feature requests and **bug reports**.
>
> **Tim**. Founder and Developer. ([timspalding](http://www.librarything.com/profile/timspalding); tim{at}librarything.com)
> **Chris H**. Developer. ([conceptDawg](http://www.librarything.com/profile/conceptDawg); christopher{at}librarything.com)
> **Mike**. Developer. ([miketopper](http://www.librarything.com/profile/miketopper); mike{at}librarything.com)

From their [contact page](http://www.librarything.com/contact).

Answer (score 3):

I'm the sysadmin for LibraryThing and we had a problem with one of our rules in our SSL vhost.

Hopefully this should be fixed for you now. I'm very sorry this caused so much trouble.

Comment: Awesome, back to filing books :)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, we prefer to put issues on the Bug Collectors group: http://www.librarything.com/groups/bugcollectors

We welcome emails, but we'd probably post to there anyway, since it helps us track issues.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried (via HTTP), but a JavaScript error prevented me from submitting (as pointed out above).